Is there a R function which tells not to overrule values used in a loop by values with the same name in a function?
I want to perform a Deterministic sensitivity analysis (DSA) with the lower limits of a few parameters of my Markov model. I have put these lower limits in a dataframe called parameter_values. Next, I want to perform a loop where in each loop a value of this dataframe is used and outcomes are calculated:
`for (parameter in names(parameter_values)) {
value <- parameter_values[[parameter]]
outcome <- CE(parameter, value)
result_df <- rbind(result_df, data.frame(Parameter = parameter, Value = value, Outcome = outcome))
}`
CE is my function for my Markov model.
The problem is that the values in parameter_values are overruled by the values in the CE function. Can I add a function in CE that tells that it needs to take the value of parameter_value in stead the one that is defined in CE?
I tried to put parameter_value in a different environment. I also tried to call the dataframe within the CE function, but this does not change anything.
